# Twinkle, twinkle little star, how I wonder which game you are?

Tags: game-identification

I was browsing through some photos and I had stumbled upon this one. It appears to be a very creepy game that I might be interested in, unfortunately google image search did not return any results.

What game does this belong to? I am very curious on why I would never sing *Twinkle Twinkle Little Star* again.

[image: Picture from game]

Comment: As interesting as the title was, it doesn't do anything to help figure out what was being asked.

Comment: @GodEmperorDune May I asked why you reverted Franks updates

Comment: @Wondercricket The original title clearly indicated that this question was to identify a game, and the "twinkle twinkle little star" makes it more likely to be higher in search results. Plus its fun.

Comment: @Wondercricket After [some discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30763582#30763582), it was decided that your original title, humor and all, was an acceptable title. Also, it made the question more easily searchable given the image in the question, if I'm not misunderstanding the discussion.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Dead Space 2, Ive seen the beginning of that game too many times not to know.

Comment: Yea its a great game. One of the scariest games I have ever played. Thank you too!

Comment: As someone who hasn't played Dead Space 2, I'm still wondering what Twinkle Twinkle Little Star has to do with any of this.

Comment: @DcShannon I watched the video it's referencing, and Twinkle Twinkle is sung very eeriely and creepily in the game

Answer (score 8):

As [Daniel Seales wrote](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272016/twinkle-twinkle-little-star-how-i-wonder-which-game-you-are/272017#272017), the picture is from the [Dead Space 2](http://store.steampowered.com/app/47780/).

As for the lullaby Twinkle, Twinkle, Little Star it was first featured in one of the trailers of [first Dead Space](http://store.steampowered.com/app/17470) called Dead Space Lullaby Trailer:

I highly recommend watching it, it is one of my favorite trailers of all time.

The trailer was also featured in the game as screensaver for the main menu, and can be heard in a few times in the actual game and in its sequel. Without spoiling anything I can tell you that the picture is referring to one of more memorable moments when it can be heard. Dead Space 1 and 2 was a great examples of a sci-fi themed survival horror, If you like such things I highly recommend trying them.